# My Joomla site shows PHP error: failed to open stream

Tags: php, joomla

I am working on a Joomla site, and just recently updated PHP to 7.2, but my site started throwing errors. I have also updated Joomla to the latest version, but errors still appear. I'm not good in PHP and don't know how to fix it.

```html
Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Color has a deprecated constructor in /public_html/templates/jf_social/features/color.php on line 11

Warning: require_once(/public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public_html/templates/jf_social/error.php on line 52

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php' (include_path='.:/php:/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/share/pear') in /public_html/templates/jf_social/error.php on line 52
```

I think error comes from my Joomla template, I am using this one https://www.joomforest.com/joomla/templates/jf-social

I can't receive support from that template developers, because my subscription is expired, and changing the template will take a lot of time for me,
can you please anyone advise how to fix it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: File /public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php does not exist. Show  the content of /public_html/templates/jf_social/error.php please.

Comment: in your color.php file at line 11, it seems that a class has a constructor which has the same name as the class itself. Now, the constructor function should be named `__construct` instead of the class name. See PHP doc here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete the line 52

```
require_once(/public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php)
```

from the File

```
/public_html/templates/jf_social/error.php
```

The renderer/head.php doesnt be supported any more in your joomla version. If there are no more errors, everything is fine, if not your template is not supported any more.

Then go to the file

```
/public_html/templates/jf_social/features/color.php
```

and edit the line

```
function Color($hex){
```

to

```
function __construct($hex){
```

Comment: https://www.joomforest.com/help/forum/jf-social-pre-purchase-questions/8960-php-7-2-and-jomsocial-error

Comment: I wouldn't personnally remove a require_once() statement because it might break the rest of the theme. It seems that the theme just needs to be updated to a new version compatible with PHP 7.2.

Comment: thank you so much! I replaced those codes and it does not show any more errors. For 3 weeks this error appeared on my website. God bless you!